# Prove that for any triangle: $(a-b) \cos \hat{C} = c(\cos\hat{B}-\cos \hat{A}) \Rightarrow a = b , \hat{A} = \hat{B}$

Tags: geometry, triangles

I'm working on this problem (which must be very easy but for some reason I can't see the solution): Suppose that you know that $$(a-b) \cos \hat{C} = c(\cos\hat{B}-\cos \hat{A}),$$ now prove that $a=b$ and that $ \hat{A}=\hat{B}$. I'm inclined to use the law of cosines:
$$a^2 = b^2 + c^2 - 2bc \cos \hat{A}$$
$$b^2 = a^2 + c^2 - 2ac \cos \hat{B}$$
$$c^2 = a^2 + b^2 - 2bc \cos \hat{C}$$
but that didn't lead me anywhere in particular. 
Any leads/hints/solutions/ideas?

Comment: Which sides are equal?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner, no you have to prove that $a = b$. So you have to prove that the triangle is an isosceles triangle. I see that the title can be misleading, so i'll update it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Use the Theorem of cosines:
$$(a-b)\left(\frac{a^2+b^2-c^2}{2ab}\right)=c\left(\frac{a^2+c^2-b^2}{2ac}-\frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc}\right)$$
and the right-Hand side simplifies to $$c\left(1/2\,{\frac { \left( a-b \right)  \left( a+b+c \right)  \left( a+b-c
 \right) }{acb}}
\right)$$
Can you finish?

Comment: Perfectly, thanks! However: I think it's easier if you put the RH-side on denominator $ab$, it simplifies a lot.

Comment: after seeing a solution it is easy to find a simplier one! But anyway, thank you for the flowers!

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$a=b\cos\hat{C}+c\cos\hat{A}$$ (for a=b)

And use: $$a=2R\sin\hat{A},b=2R\sin\hat{B}$$ in previous result for $\hat{A}=\hat{B}$

Comment: You can't use $a=b$, that's what you have to prove...

Comment: @querty: I don't believe the hint is to *use* $a=b$. It's simply to note that $a=b \cos C + c \cos A$ ... and, likewise, $b = a \cos C + c \cos A$. With these, the exercise's given equation rearranges to *imply* $a=b$. (I don't see much point in a separate argument for $\angle A = \angle B$, though. The Isosceles Triangle Theorem takes care of that.)